# How do I get one common instance of ApplicationContext using Spring in Java

Tags: spring

I know that Spring is most useful for dependency injection. But what I don't understand is how do I have one common "ApplicationContext ac=....." for the whole project, lets say I have a WebApplication and it has multiple number of packages but all of them still in one project , so how do I make the ApplicationContext instantiate only once. I had read somewhere that in Spring objects are initialized only once something as singleton beans but what I dont understand is that how is it different than Singleton design pattern, there is one question on this in SO but I couldn't quite clearly understand the answer as I am a newbie to Spring trying to learn by myself. Any help would really be appreciated. Sorry if the Q is too long. Hope I was able to explain my doubt clearly.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to accomplish and why?

Comment: I am just curious sir, if one instance of ApplicaitonContext from which we all call ac.getbean('xyz') is possible to get and second part of the question is also just for "good to know" purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Spring veans are by default Singleton, although it is possible to configure them as prototype which means that a new bean will be created upon each request. In practice, singleton means one instance per context and are their lifecycle is managed by Spring nwhich also provides hooks into the various stages. Spring does not manage prototype beans once they have been created.

It is common in a SpringMVC application to have more than one context (one for the business services, the other for the web controllers). You would only need to create an `ApplicationContext` when building a standalone application. SpringMVC applications use the `ContextLoaderListener` to create the necessary contexts.